# how to scan a vehicle license plate on android

Tags: android

I am working on a mobile app with java in android studio, it should scan the license plates of the vehicles taking a picture with the camera and write the scanned license plate in a text box.

I'm using callback but it doesn't recognize TakePicture and PictureCallBack.
[Screen1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tiJfp.jpg)
[Screen2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5TIUL.jpg)

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder.Callback;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.util.SparseArray;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.Frame;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.text.TextBlock;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.text.TextRecognizer;


public class main_camsacnner extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Camera mCamera;
    private SurfaceView mPreview;
    private Button mCaptureButton;
    private TextView mResultTextView;
    private TextRecognizer mTextRecognizer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_camsacnner);

        mPreview = findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
        mCaptureButton = findViewById(R.id.btn_capture);
        mResultTextView = findViewById(R.id.tv_result);

        mPreview.getHolder().addCallback((Callback) this);

        mCaptureButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPictureCallback);
            }
        });

        mTextRecognizer = new TextRecognizer.Builder(getApplicationContext()).build();
        if (!mTextRecognizer.isOperational()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Text recognizer could not be set up on your device :(", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
        }
    }

    private Camera.PictureCallback mPictureCallback = new Camera.PictureCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
            Frame frame = new Frame.Builder().setBitmap(bitmap).build();
            SparseArray<TextBlock> textBlocks = mTextRecognizer.detect(frame);
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < textBlocks.size(); i++) {
                TextBlock textBlock = textBlocks.valueAt(i);
                stringBuilder.append(textBlock.getValue());
            }
        }
    };
}
```

I don't know the cause of this error, I have tried to compile and it doesn't throw any code error, I run the program but it returns error:

03/23 21:03:55: Launching 'app' on Pixel 2 API 24.
Install successfully finished in 2 s 437 ms.
Could not identify launch activity: Default Activity not found
Error while Launching activity
Failed to launch an application on all devices

Answer (score 0):

Regarding on this error:

> Could not identify launch activity: Default Activity not found Error while Launching activity Failed to launch an application on all devices

Make sure you have set your targeted launching Activity to have category `LAUNCHER` in **AndroidManifest.xml**:

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

So your **AndroidManifest.xml** should look like this:

```xml
...
    <activity
        android:name=".main_camsacnner"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
          <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
          </intent-filter>
    </activity>
...
```

---

If the above is present in your **AndroidManifest** file, you can try to refresh cache of your IDE:
*File > Invalidate Caches / Restart ... > Invalidate and Restart*